# Slow form submission

Tags: html

When I submit a form, I can see my browser's progress bar slowly increased, it takes 4-6s to submit a form.
It was a generic form like :

```
<form id="someid" name="someName" action="someAction.do">
   ...
</form>
```

I test it in IE8 and Firefox 3,both are very slow.
My network condition is fine, my server works great.
What could be the problem?

Comment: Paste your exact code in here, a generic <form> tag doesn't tell us much :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your server-side code is slow.